# Python script to push text file commands over SSH

Tags: python, ssh

I am trying to find a solution (if is possible) to create a python script that pushes a configuration text file (batch of commands ~ 1000s of lines) over ssh.

So far, I have a solution to push few commands, but it doesn't apply when there are 1000s of lines.

Comment: What do you mean, "push"? Are you trying to copy a file? If so why can't you use scp?

Comment: Remote device is a Huawei switch. By push I mean to deploy all the commands contained in the text file at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard about [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/resources/get-started)? It does the job you want to do, and it's written mostly in python.

> App deployment, configuration management, and orchestration — all from
>   one system. Ansible is simple, agentless automation that anyone can
>   use.

[Ansible Documentaion](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_getting_started.html)

Long story short you writte playboks (.yaml templates). Simply put, playbooks are the basis for a really simple configuration management and multi-machine deployment system, unlike any that already exist, and one that is very well suited to deploying complex applications.

Example playbook:

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  vars:
    http_port: 80
    max_clients: 200
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: ensure apache is at the latest version
    yum:
      name: httpd
      state: latest
  - name: write the apache config file
    template:
      src: /srv/httpd.j2
      dest: /etc/httpd.conf
    notify:
    - restart apache
  - name: ensure apache is running
    service:
      name: httpd
      state: started
  handlers:
    - name: restart apache
      service:
        name: httpd
        state: restarted
```

When you will create playbook that suits your needs just run it against your machine or list of them. There is a huge list of [modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/modules_by_category.html) available to ansible ready to use. You can also write your own plugins.